Thunderbird, evolution, snap, a.s.o. removed after fail installation of ssh. Recovery possible?
OS: Ubuntu Oracular (24.10)
Thunderbird, evolution, snap, a.s.o. removed after fail installation of ssh.server Recovery possible?
"upgrade" means the installation of ssh server.
Installation didn't match. I've searched about the
fail message during installation here on the forum.
The advice was to repeat the procedure after uninstall the
ssh-client. But this lead to damage of the home installation.
I've followed instruction on youtube:
OpenSSH for Absolute Beginners
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FKsdbjzBcc.
(The user comments there are positive).
Background of my activity are attacks on my computers.
Its actually not possible to create an Ubuntu live system or
tails. The SHA doesn't match on all pc's.
Obviously the download and my activity on the computers are tracked and manipulated.
The USB sticks don't boot as well.
I cant find a solution to copy the log file from
the terminal. I send a copy from the first terminal page as attachment.


Please edit your question to 1) Explain the exact release of Ubuntu, and 2) Show us the complete and accurate set of terminal commands that you actually used, Your terminal command history can be accessed using the history command. 3) If possible show us the complete terminal output of this catastrophic event, Apt terminal output is stored in /var/log/apt/term.log

In almost all cases data recovery is possible, but to provide specific help, we need specific details & you've provided none. We don't know what Ubuntu product you are using, what versions & how those software apps were installed; what was done creating the problem etc.. Your question is unclear without anything specific we can help with due to lack of detail.

I've edit my text on your comment.

Removed the misleading "upgrade" tag. We still need to see #2: The exact commands you used. It's clear from your output that there is extensive damage to your to system. It can probably be fixed, and that repair will be much easier when we know exactly what you did. The ENTIRE sequence of that session. Omit nothing.

Copying from a terminal: Highlight using your mouse, then CTRL + SHIFT + C. Or right-click on the highlighted area.

"The SHA doesn't match on all pc's. Obviously the download and my activity on the computers are tracked and manipulated. The USB sticks don't boot as well." Well, let's not jump to conclusions. That's not actually an obvious conclusion at all. Several other non-nefarious possibilities are much more likely.

Who reminds at the exactly command after such stress situation.
There is the copy from the apt log. The whole log is being copied as pdf
or txt-file. Don't know howto send this here.
There was a simple uninstall command of the ssh client which caused the damage.
The logs are obviously not so usefull and informative.

We're not asking you to remember. The machine records your commands. We are asking you to use the history command to access that information. See the #2 instructions above. The apt log you sent should be enough of that file. But we do still need your commands.

"Copying from a terminal: Highlight using your mouse, then CTRL +
SHIFT + C. Or right-click on the highlighted area. – "
user535733
1.Info goes over several screens. No scrolling possible.
2. There is only the history from today.
How to load the "history" from an earlier date?

Meanwhile I've installed thunderbird again.
It has stopped with recovering e-mails from the early summer?

#2 used commands:
-sudo apt install openssh-server
(...server has no installation candidate...)
-sudo apt-get remove openssh-client
(which caused the problem described here)
-sudo apt update
-sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Meanwhile that seems to be rather as bad surprise than support.
This is not acceptable especially by the administrators here.

The user who took contact are mute for unknown reasons :user535733, guiverc
Their questions about the commands were answered.
I'm deeply concerned about them and the administration of Ask Ubuntu who suppresses the topic and other contacts. Obviously for the most of the time here.
